# RemoteCommand, is not sending parameters in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

When I try to send parameters via remote command, it doesn't send, it arrives as null in java.

My javascript function is not leaving.

example.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">
        
        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function customfunction() {
            console.log("not here!");
                myMethod([{name: "parm", value: "ok"}]);
        }
    </script>

    <h:form id="dashboardForm" includeViewParams="true">    
        <p:remoteCommand name="myMethod"  action="#{exampleBean.javaMethod}" autoRun="true" />
    

    </h:form>

    ( ... )
</ui:define>



exampleBean.java

(...)


public void javaMethod() {
    String selectedValue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("parm");         
    this.result = selectedValue;
    
    this.result = selectedValue;
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println(this.result);
}

(...)
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't write an extensive comment but these things happen too often that I just write short stacatto remarks: 1: No version info, 2: no [mcve] , 3: see also https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for [mcve] related things. 4: Where did you see the `includeViewParams` on an `h:form` is supported?

Comment: is just replace :    function customfunction() {  ->  for: $(document).ready(function() {.and remove  autoRun="true" on remoteCommand.